# Set method definition in list class Java

Tags: java, list

I wanted to ask how to define set method in java List class. I have the example of get method, but I don't know how to define set method, same with add method. Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public E get(int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k >= size) {
        return null;
    }
    current = first.findNode(k);
    return current.element;
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  In general, though, setters would have an argument passed to them and use that to assign the variable: `public void setElement(int k)` or something like that.

Comment: The get method in `List` returns the item at the specified index. What is your set method supposed to do?

Comment: `List` is an interface. Are you writing your own implementation?

Comment: Yes. I am writing my own implementation. I know that I can  import java.util.ArrayList and then use it like this arrlist.set(2,55) (for example). But I can't use it in my case. I created my own list and in that list I need to define set method.

Comment: Read [the Wikipedia page on mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) with an [example for Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Java_example). And please search and study existing Questions on Stack Overflow before posting. For example, the [four thousand hits on `java setter method`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+setter+method).

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `set` method implementation should meet the contract of `set` method defined in JavaDoc of `java.util.List` (see link below). So it should return values and throws exception as is described in the JavaDoc. The way to implement it depends on what you want to use for storing list elements.

> E set(int index,
>         E element)
>
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation).
>
> Parameters:
>
> index - index of the element to replace
>
> element - element to be stored at the specified position
>
> Returns:
>
> the element previously at the specified position
>
> ...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-